# Extjs 3.4 : ColumnModel Renderer to other dataIndex?

Tags: extjs3

my reader :

```
var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
     totalProperty: 'total',
     successProperty: 'success',
     idProperty: 'id_k',
     root: 'rows',
     messageProperty: 'message'  // <-- New "messageProperty" meta-data }, [
     {name: 'id_k'},    {name: 'nm_kb', allowBlank: false},
     {name: 'id_p'},    {name: 'nm_p', allowBlank: false} ]);
```

my column :

> `{header: "Provinsi", width: 100, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id_p'}`

**How i can make dataIndex: 'id_p' appear as 'nm_p' but still dataIndex: 'id_p'?**

i want it show 'nm_p'....

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a renderer on the column:

```
var Provinsi = {
   header: 'Provinsi',
   dataIndex: 'id_p',
   renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
      return record.data.nm_p;
   }
}
```

[Link to documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-cfg-renderer)

Comment: Up vote by pressing the up arrow above the 0 and accept the answer by ticking the tick mark below the 0. :)

Comment: Alright.. You can accept the answer though. That'll help others having the same issue as you did :)